Update docker image from existing fails to run initial image application
I'm trying to customize postgres container with a automatic backups. So, I've created a Dockerfile for that, where I've placed the appropriate logic:
#   Dockerfile to create image with cron services
FROM postgres:16.2

#   Install Cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron

RUN mkdir /backup

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

COPY ./backup /etc/cron.d/backup

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/backup

# Add the script to the Docker Image
COPY ./backup.sh /etc/cronjobs/backup.sh
RUN chmod +x /etc/cronjobs/backup.sh

# Give execution rights on the cron scripts
RUN chmod 0744 /etc/cronjobs/backup.sh

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/backup

# Start the cron service
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

So, when I'm using this Dockerfile - the new image looks fine. All files & cron is properly copied. The only thing is that postgres is now being started after that :)
When I look at postgres:16.2 layers (postgres:16.2 layers) - I can see that the last command launches postgres:
CMD ["postgres"]

So basically, I've tried to provide this command to launch both cron & postgres:
CMD ["cron", "tail -f /var/log/cron.log", "postgres"]

But it looks like it should be handled in a different way.
What is the right way to create a Dockerfile in such case?

You could write and entrypoint script that would run postgres and then cron

As @ChrisDoyle said. you should probably use entrypoint script for this. We use one for init of cron and kerberos auth.
Example:
#!/bin/sh
sudo cron
kinit XYZ
klist
Append CMD from Dockerfile
exec "$@"
And then inside Dockerfile:
COPY the launch scripts
COPY ./ci/launch.sh /usr/local/bin/launch.sh
#Switch to application user
USER appuser
#Launch our entrypoint script
ENTRYPOINT ["launch.sh"]
#Launch our application
CMD ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]

I probably wouldn't write a Dockerfile at all.  Use your host system's cron daemon, and use pg_dump installed on the host system to call the database.

The trick here is that a container only runs one process.  So if you need a database and a cron daemon, typically you'd run these in two separate containers.

Thanks for your help. @DavidMaze I like your idea, because it looks simpler to use a single host cron. Besides, it looks normal for a container to run a single process. Thanks!
